# Losing characters when dragging text inside a <textarea>

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, textarea

While making an internal tool for our team, I've encountered something strange, and can't seem to find anything on this.

It involves a <textarea> that allows editing a Blade template. However, for some selections, when the selection is dragged to anywhere in the area, some text will be lost and replaced by an underscore.

There are workarounds, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>, but I prefer at least to understand it.

[Here's three example moves, one of them shows the glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3UQE.png)

It happens around {{ $var }}.

Select just the "{{ $var }}" part, and it drags fine.
Select a little more, and it depends.

It seems to be very specific. You must select [a-z], then ":", optional whitespace and then the blade tag. But then if you select more text and a little bit from the previous line, it works as expected again.

It happens in both Chrome and Edge browsers. I'm on Windows 10.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4x83L9z7/

```
<textarea style="width: 300px; height: 150px;">
    lorem ipsum
    Country: {{ $country }}
    dolor sit amet
</textarea>
```

***Update:** I figured that you only need the colon, ":", for reproducing this glitch. So forget about Blade. While this makes the glitch far more likely to happen, it seems nobody but me has yet encountered it in <textarea> history...*

Comment: What is a Blade template? Something [related to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel#Features) [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel)?

Comment: Exactly!
This glitch isn't caused by Blade or Laravel though, to reproduce, all that's needed is a textarea with some of that {{ $var }} action in it.